# How to extract foreground image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing, matlab-cvst

I have an .avi file (taken from [Actions as Space-Time Shapes - Classification Dataset](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/SpaceTimeActions.html)) from which I've extracted the frames in .png format. Now, I want to do foreground detection from these images using Matlab.

I've seen one code which uses `vision.ForegroundDetector()`, but it works for video files.

So please if anyone can give me the code foreground detection for images, then I'll be really thankful.

This is an example of a frame:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Two things are probably needed before you are going to get an answer, first, define background and second, it would be better/appreciated by the community if you showed some of the code you've already tried.

Comment: You have extracted the video frames, but the algorithm you want to use works on video. So why not use the algorithm on the original video? And what you want to do is background detection, and there are plenty of papers (google is your friend).

Answer (score 5):

Since this video is taken with stabilized camera, you can easily do background subtraction:

```
%// read the video:
reader = VideoReader('daria_walk.avi');
vid = {};
while hasFrame(reader)
    vid{end+1} = im2single(readFrame(reader));
end
%// simple background estimation using mean:
bg = mean( cat(4, vid{:}), 4 );
%// estimate foreground as deviation from estimated background:
fIdx = 43; %// do it for frame 43
fg = sum( abs( vid{fIdx} - bg ), 3 ) > 0.25;
```

Now you can see the results:

```
figure;
subplot(131); imshow( bg ); 
subplot(132); imshow( vid{fIdx} );
subplot(133); imshow( fg );
```

Resulting with
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `vision.ForegroundDetector`. It takes images, which can come from a video file or from individual image files.